# meaning of "curt"

Tags: meaning

A [post](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/okay-ok-k-workplace-language_l_5c619182e4b0910c63f35750) says

> Gretchen McCulloch, an internet linguist and author of the upcoming
>   book Because Internet, said OK is not inherently rude but the length
>   of a reply matters.
>
> “Anything that’s shorter can sound **curter**, anything that’s longer can
>   sound more polite,” McCulloch said. In other words, your “kay” may
>   sound like a throwaway answer to the recipient.

[Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition of "curt"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curt?q=curter)

> If someone's manner or speech is curt, it is rude as a result of being very quick

Does that means

> Suppose one speaks 150 words per minute on average. People would consider someone who speaks 200 words per minute rude.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where your "words per minute" idea came from... remember that the article deals with a **reply**, and not general speech. People _speak_ at different speeds. I can think of two reasons why a very short _reply_ could be considered rude: (1) If someone asks a question expecting a well thought out reply, a very short reply ignores that expectation; and (2) It can come across as very aggressive in some settings, as if to say "_Here's my answer. Conversation over._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! Cambridge's definition is unhelpful. It's more like an example than a definition.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/curt) defines curt as *rudely brief*. It is the **brevity** which is rude: not the speed. The word *brusque* has an almost identical meaning.

Someone speaking at high speed would more likely be deemed odd or eccentric than rude.

Btw, there's no such word as *curter*.

Comment: Thank you. could "curter" be the comparative of "curt"?

Comment: Yes, obviously that is what it is intended to be. The more reputable online dictionaries don't give _curter_ as a valid word. Use _more curt_ instead.